# Two different ways of writing the variance of the empirical distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

My statistics note states that the variance of the empirical distribution is
$v= \sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar x )^2\frac {1} {n}$ which the author then re-writes as
$v= \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2 (\frac {1} {n}) - \bar x^2$. How is this achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just algebra

$$
\begin{aligned}
v&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})^2=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(x_i^2-2x_i\bar{x}+\bar{x}^2\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2-2\bar{x}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i+\bar{x}^2\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n1\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2-2\bar{x}^2+\bar{x}^2\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2-\bar{x}^2
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Ok thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})^2=\frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2-2\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\cdot \bar{x}+\sum_{i=1}^n \bar{x}^2\right)=\frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2-2\bar{x}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i+\bar{x}^2\sum_{i=1}^n 1\right).$$

Hence

$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})^2=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2-2\bar{x}\cdot\bar{x}+\frac{1}{n}\cdot n \bar{x}^2=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2-\bar{x}^2.
$$

Answer (score 2):

A useful idea is to consider sample mean, variance, moments, quantiles etc as the mean, variance etc with respect to the *empirical measure*. Namely, the sample mean $\overline x$ is the expectation of empirical measure, which assigns probabilities $1/n$ to the sampled values $\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\}$:
$$
\overline x = \hat{\mathbb{E}}_n X,
$$
where $\hat{\mathbb{P}}_n(X = x_k) = 1/n$, $k=1,\dots,n$. Similarly, the sample variance 
$$
\hat\sigma^2 = \frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n (x_k-\overline x)^2 = \hat{\mathbb{E}}_n (X -\hat{\mathbb{E}}_n X)^2 = \hat{\operatorname{var}}_n(X) 
$$
is the variance of $X$ with respect to $\hat{\mathbb{P}}_n$. Thus, the formula
$$
\hat\sigma^2 = \overline{x^2} - (\overline x)^2 = \hat{\mathbb{E}}_n X^2 - (\hat{\mathbb{E}}_n X)^2
$$
is a particular case of the general formula for variance.